# I am trying to make an object detection app on flutter but it keeps crashing as soon as i press the button to open camera

Tags: flutter, dart, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying to make a flutter app which detects objects and puts bounding boxes around them. First when i got the camera feed it was working fine but when i loaded the model and tried to run it, it just would'nt work and would crash in 2 3 seconds.

I have tried everything from optimizing the model to changing the model itself but nothing seems to work, any help would be appreciated. I am attaching the entire code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

late List<CameraDescription> _cameras;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _cameras = await availableCameras();
  await loadModel();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> loadModel() async {
  String? res = await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/ssdmobilenet.tflite",
      labels: "assets/label2.txt",
      numThreads: 4, // defaults to 1
      isAsset:
          true, // defaults to true, set to false to load resources outside assets
      useGpuDelegate:
          false // defaults to false, set to true to use GPU delegate
      );
  print('model loaded successfully');
}

Future<List<dynamic>?> runModelOnFrame(CameraImage image) async {
  var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnFrame(
    bytesList: image.planes.map((plane) {
      return plane.bytes;
    }).toList(),
    model: "YOLO",
    imageHeight: image.height,
    imageWidth: image.width,
    imageMean: 0, // defaults to 127.5
    imageStd: 255, // defaults to 127.5
    threshold: 0.2, // defaults to 0.1
    numResultsPerClass: 1,
  );
  print('Found ${recognitions?.length ?? 0} objects');
  return recognitions;
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FIrstPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FIrstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FIrstPage({Key? key});

  @override
  State<FIrstPage> createState() => _FIrstPageState();
}

class _FIrstPageState extends State<FIrstPage> {
  String buttonName = 'HEYO';
  int currentIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('App Bar'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: currentIndex == 0
            ? Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        onPrimary: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext conext) =>
                                Scaffold(body: const CameraApp()),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(buttonName),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) => const NewPage(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Text(buttonName),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            : Image.asset('images/light.jpg'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'home', icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(label: 'settings', icon: Icon(Icons.settings))
        ],
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewPage({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraApp extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Default Constructor
  const CameraApp({Key? key});

  @override
  State<CameraApp> createState() => _CameraAppState();
}

class _CameraAppState extends State<CameraApp> {
  bool isProcessingFrame = false;
  late CameraController controller;
  List<Widget> boxesWidgets = [];
  int processingFrames = 0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = CameraController(_cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
      controller.startImageStream(_onImageAvailable);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _onImageAvailable(CameraImage image) async {
    processingFrames++;
    if (isProcessingFrame) {
      return;
    }
    isProcessingFrame = true;
    processingFrames++;

    if (processingFrames >= 3) {
      processingFrames = 0;
    }
    List<dynamic>? recognitions = await runModelOnFrame(image);
    if (recognitions != null) {
      List<Widget> boxes = [];
      for (var recognition in recognitions) {
        double confidence = recognition['confidence'];
        if (confidence >= 0.1) {
          int index = recognition['index'];
          String label = recognition['label'];
          double left = recognition['rect']['x'];
          double top = recognition['rect']['y'];
          double width = recognition['rect']['w'];
          double height = recognition['rect']['h'];
          double right = left + width;
          double bottom = top + height;

          // Convert coordinates from relative [0, 1] range to absolute values.
          left *= image.width;
          top *= image.height;
          width *= image.width;
          height *= image.height;
          right *= image.width;
          bottom *= image.height;

          boxes.add(
            Positioned(
              left: left,
              top: top,
              width: width,
              height: height,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$label ${(confidence * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        boxesWidgets = boxes;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return Container();
    }

    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final deviceRatio = size.width / size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: deviceRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
          ),
          ...boxesWidgets,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.stopImageStream();
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add ??? in your first line label.txt

1. ???
2. class1
3. class2

Answer (score 0):

Note one thing if you have YOLO model v3 flutter_tflite package will work but flutter_tflite package is not compatible with higher versions of YOLO models(Your app will crash).
if you are using YOLO model with higher versions like v8 etc go for the flutter_vision package.